# how to switch assets based on the platform: flash for windows and HTML5 for ios

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am an eLearning developer and use **animated flash (*swf)** in my courses.

We offer the same courses in html5 format aimed for ipad: Flash to html 5 conversion done using Google Swiffy.

The drawback is the same content is packaged twice - one with flash and other with Html5, and placed at two different location and the learner can register to either version, based on the device he/she is going to use to access the course.

I believe this is not the correct strategy, and I should be able to offer the course as a single package.

Can anyone help how to switch swf with the equivalent html5 snippet, by automatically detecting the platform the content being accessed?

Thank you in advance.

P.S: Many of the learners still use old version of IE and we could not offer HTML5 alone.

Answer (score 0):

It's must be to help for detect your device :

```
 var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```